# jasmine: unit test a standalone Promise function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

Iam new to jasmine and nodejs.
I am curious is there any simple way to test below function which returns a promise.

```
 public async getSalIncreaseData(queryParams: Params, childNode: string, careerTrackId: string): Promise<any> {   
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.salModel
        .query(someQuery)
        .loadAll()
        .exec((error, data) => {
          if (error) {           
            reject(error);
          } else {
            resolve(data);
          }
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: There is. It's not a standalone function, is it? Looks more like TS method. Consider providing all relevant code. Promises can be handled with https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers or with Jasmine itself in latest framework versions.

Comment: can u please show me how to write a simple unit test for this function

Comment: You haven't specified where this function is defined, so I cannot say how it should be tested. *Consider providing all relevant code*.

Comment: suppose this function is called by an object some thing like :

obj.getSalIncreaseData(param1,param2,param3);